Find a $m>0$ such that $(1+|x|)^{-m} f(x) \in L^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right) $
Consider $f \in L_{l o c}^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ and $T_f$ is the regular distribution associated to $f$. Assume now $f \in L_{l o c}^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$, nonnegative satisfying $T_f \in \mathscr{S}^{\prime}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$(tempered distribution). Prove that there exists $m>0$ such that $(1+|x|)^{-m} f(x) \in L^1\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$, how to do this, I want to use norm of a smooth functions in Schwartz space, in which a $(1+|x|)^{m}$ occur in inequality, then I don't know how to proceed

I think it is easier to look at $<f, \varphi(\bullet - x)>$ for a test function $\varphi$ which is 1 on say $[-1,1]^n$.

Here is my first attempt,we only need to check the property of $f$ at points far away from 0,
let $\eta _{R}$ be a cut-off function(a cut off function is of course in schwartz space), we need to following lemma
lemma1:Consider a cut-off function $\eta \in \mathscr{D}\left(B_2\right)$ such that $\eta \equiv 1$ in $B_1$, and $\eta_R(x)=\eta(x / R)$ for $ R$ ,$R>0$.then  for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $C>0$ (depend on k) such that
$$
(1+|x|)^k \sum_{|\alpha| \leq k}\left|\partial^\alpha \eta_R(x)\right| \leq C(1+R)^k, \quad \forall R \geq 1
$$
then we can let $\eta _{R}$ be $1$ on $B(0,R)$, be greater than $\frac{2}{3}$ on $B(0,\frac{3}{2}R)-B(0,R)$, and be zero outside $B(0,2R)$, and we can also assume that the cut-off function varies quite uniform on the non-constant interval, then we can use the theorem that determine whether the functional is continuous on schwartz space, that is:
Theorem 1 (Continuity Test) A linear map $f: \varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto\langle f, \varphi\rangle \in \mathbb{C}$ is continuous if and only if there are constants $C>0$(depend only on f) and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
|\langle f, \varphi\rangle| \leq C \sum_{0 \leq n, m \leq N}\|\varphi\|_{n, m}
$$
in which $\|\varphi\|_{n, m}=\sup _{x \in \mathbb{R}}\left|x^n \varphi^{(m)}(x)\right|$, then we can act the distribution associated with $f$ on $\eta _{R}$ for a given large $R$, we get(notice that both $f$ and $\eta _{R}$ are nonnegative)$$\int _{B(0,\frac{3}{2}R)-B(0,R)}\frac{1}{2}fdx\leq \int _{B(0,2R)}f\eta _{R}dx\leq Csup((1+\left | x \right |)^{N}(\sum_{k\leq N}^{}D^{k}\eta _{R}))\leq C'(1+R)^{N}$$(notice that $\frac{3}{2}>\frac{1}{2}$ and also as $R$ tend to infinity, the non-constant interval for cut-off function become larger and we assume that the cut-off function varies "uniformly", so the slope is more and more gentle, hence the sum of the derivative with given order is bounded above and and we also choose out a part of the whole integration area in which the cut-off function is greater than 1/2), so multiply both side by 2, we get the following $$\int _{B(0,\frac{3}{2}R)-B(0,R)}fdx\leq C'(1+R)^{N})$$, we are integrating left-most part on a ball, hence we can write the right-most term in the form of integration of a one-variable function with respect to $r$ and write the right most term as $$\int _{B(0,2R)}C''(1+r)^{N-1}dr+M\leq \int _{B(0,2R)}C'''(1+r)^{N-1}dr$$(we know $(1+mR)^{N}\leq C(m,N)(1+R)^{N}$ for positive $m$),$M$ is the value of the derivative at zero, hence we have $f< (1+\left | x \right |)^{N-1}$ on a large ring of region with inner radius of $R$, since $M$ has nothing to do with $R$ since $R=0$ at zero and $C''$ depends only on $N$ and $f$, so these two constants have nothing to do with $R$, hence we can divide these two numbers by a $(1+\left | x \right |)^{l}$ with sufficient large l and get an integrable function at points far away from 0.
